# How to make an empty array of array's in python

Tags: python, arrays, empty-list

I wrote a code to do some kind of algorithm. For this I need a array of array's like:
`d = [[1,4,5], [0,3,6,1], [7,3]]`.
I made an randomizer to get random data to work with. For this randomizer i need to start with an empty list like:
`d = [[][][]]` This works well, but when i change the number of rows in my algorithm i have to change this by hand. Is there a way to change the number automatically? I tried:

```
d = []*10
```

and

```
d = []
for i in range(1, n+1):
    d[i] = []
```

but both do not work.

Comment: Do `d = [[] for _ in range(n)]`.  Your second example will also work if you do `d.append([])` instead of `d[i] = []`.  The first example will *almost* do what you want if you do `d = [[]] * 10`, but you'll actually end up with 10 references to one list and have some very mystifying bugs as a result.

Comment: note, these are *lists* not arrays

Comment: Thanks! It works